PHP read files and create folders on a different virtual host folder
A PHP script running on 'example.net' should be able to read files and create subfolders in a dedicated folder on 'storage.example.net'
I would like to set a 'documents' folder on a different virtual host under Apache. This is the scenario:
main host: example.net
documents host: storage.example.net;
Server path for main host: /home/example/public_html/
Server path for documents host folder: /home/storage/public_html/comp_folders/
I am gettin the error:

'failed to open dir: Permission denied'

when running the PHP script on 'example.net'. The script works ok if pointed to a local 'example.net' folder.
I tried setting full R/W/Ex permissions to the document folder (document host) but I'm still getting the same PHP error.  I would appreciate any help.

Have you checked the open_basedir setting?

Thanks Rob, I just have access to each virtual host webmin control panel, not to the main server. I tried uploading a file with 'var_dump(ini_get('open_basedir'));' to the main host where the PHP script runs but it returns an empty string.
I can ask the server's admin to modify any setting if needed.

You're trying to access the home folders of different users /home/example and /home/storage. You should move the shared folders to an appropriate place, where you have control over permissions... what you shouldn't do is to make a home folder accessible to other users...

The goal is to set up a two-virtual host scheme, the first one dedicated to running a web app, and the second one just for file storage. I planned this with security and portability in mind, now I'm reconsidering storing the files in the same host in order to avoid further issues. Maybe over 'public_html' in the folder structure so the storage is somehow independent of the web app.

what is the AllowOverride (Apache) configuration of the target vhost? Do you have SELinux running on the machine?

I'm sorry, I'm aware it should be just a comment, but I lack permissions.
What's in the script? What method do you use to authenticate?
Can you paste the file/code?
Also, you said:

when running the PHP script on 'example.net'. The script works ok if pointed to a local 'example.net' folder.

What about running the script on 'storage.example.net'? Does it also work ok?

Thanks, this is the script (it basically lists the file names in folder):

Runs fine locally, but when pointed to a different virtual host in the same server it throughs the permissions error.
